# run a parallel thread in a pipeline that does not appear to be a stage or a closure

Tags: multithreading, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline that runs let's say 50 parallel stages. In each stage, I'm starting a python script (using the `sh`, or `bat` steps) which runs all the logic required for that stage. This same python script creates a `summary.json` file which includes the tasks and their progress/status. I want to poll this file from Jenkins to update a report that I display on the build's page while the python script is running.

**Possible solutions:**

1. For each of those parallel stages, I can generate an additional "monitor" stage that keeps polling the file in the workspace for the stage its monitoring and update the report. The problem here is that I will be doubling the number of stages I have which would look awful in the pipeline view.
2. For each of those parallel stages, I can start another "thread" that would behave exactly the same as the previous option except that it won't show as a stage in the pipeline view or in BlueOcean.
3. Run the main python script in async mode (start the process in the background with a dont-kill-me flag) and then continue polling the file from the same stage. Problem here is that I will need to monitor the process PID or have some way to detect that the original process has been terminated. Another problem is that I won't be getting the logs most probably.

Anyone has any suggestions or possible solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> For each of those parallel stages, I can generate an additional "monitor" stage that keeps polling the file in the workspace for the stage it monitors and updates the report

```bash
 +----------------+                 +-------------------+
 |                |                 |                   |
 |   Parallel     |                 |   Monitor/Report  |
 |   Stages (50)  |---generates---> |   Update Thread   |
 |                |   summary.json  |                   |
 +----------------+                 +-------------------+
```

> - The scripts as part of each stage are executed on a separate node. So the Thread needs to run on the same node it's monitoring.
> - All groovy code (including this Thread) runs on the built-in node, so it won't find the files. Maybe we can adapt this and 1 thread for each stage, but that would cause tons of slowness on the controller since we'll be consuming all the threads.

Instead of creating threads manually, you can make use of Jenkins' native [`parallel` step](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/running-stages-in-parallel-jenkins-workflow-pipeline#1-parallel-blocks-in-jenkinsfile) to run tasks concurrently. Jenkins will handle the execution threads appropriately.

Since each stage runs on a separate node, you can use the `agent` directive to specify the node for each stage or parallel branch.

> That same python script creates a `summary.json` file which includes the tasks and their progress/status. I want to poll this file from Jenkins to update a report that I display on the build's page while the python script is running.

To address the need to poll the `summary.json` file for updates while the Python script is running, without doubling the number of stages and without overloading the Jenkins controller, I should not use a `while` loop to continuously poll the status of the Python script and check for the `summary.json` file. That operation is lightweight, but when scaled to many stages, it could potentially consume significant resources on the Jenkins controller if not managed properly.
I had initially done a pooling with a `sleep(15)` pause, which should prevent tight looping that could lead to high CPU utilization. However, this still means that each stage is independently performing an I/O operation every 15 seconds, which multiplies with the number of parallel stages you have.

To minimize the impact on the Jenkins controller, you might consider:

- increasing the polling interval between each poll to reduce load, if near-real-time monitoring is not required.
- making sure the file I/O operations for polling are done using asynchronous I/O if available.
- implementing a throttling mechanism to limit the number of file I/O operations across all stages within a certain timeframe.
- moving the monitoring process *outside* of Jenkins to a separate system that is responsible for watching the `summary.json` files and updating the report. That would mean your Jenkins jobs would need to communicate with this external system to provide updates.

```
def runInBackground(stageName) {
    // This function runs a Python script in the background
    // and ensures it will not be killed after the Jenkins step ends.
    sh script: "nohup python ${stageName}.py > ${stageName}_output.log 2>&1 & echo \$! > ${stageName}_pid.txt", returnStdout: false
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Execute and Monitor') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def parallelStagesMap = [:]
                    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                        def stageName = "Stage-${i}"
                        parallelStagesMap[stageName] = {
                            node {
                                // Run the Python script in the background
                                runInBackground(stageName)
                                // Read the PID
                                def pid = readFile("${stageName}_pid.txt").trim()
                                // Poll the summary.json file and logs for updates
                                while (sh(script: "ps -p ${pid}", returnStatus: true) == 0) {
                                    if (fileExists("${stageName}_summary.json")) {
                                        // Logic to update the report here
                                        // ...
                                    }
                                    // Optionally, read the latest logs and echo them for Jenkins output
                                    def logContent = readFile("${stageName}_output.log").trim()
                                    echo logContent
                                    // Sleep before polling again
                                    sleep(15)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Execute all stages in parallel
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            // Steps to collect and archive the logs from all stages
            script {
                for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                    def stageName = "Stage-${i}"
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: "${stageName}_output.log"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each Python script is started in the background with `nohup` to prevent it from being killed when the Jenkins step ends. The output is redirected to a log file.
The PID of the background process is immediately written to a file to make sure it can be accessed later.
A while loop is used to check if the process is still running and if so, to perform the necessary polling of the `summary.json` and log files.
The log file is periodically read and echoed to the Jenkins console to retain the log output in real-time.
Finally, the log files are archived for each stage in the post-build step.

If the load is still too high with these changes, an external monitoring solution might be necessary to meet all your constraints.

Note: I do not think that Jenkins natively supports updating the build page in real-time. If you want real-time updates to be displayed on the Jenkins build page, you would likely need to use a Jenkins plugin that supports this feature, or alternatively, write to a file that you then serve via HTTP and use JavaScript to poll that file and update a web page in real-time. Plugins like the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher/) could be leveraged to display the report, but for real-time updates, you may need a custom solution.

---

> Although this solution should work, there are 2 problems with it:
>
> - Since we're not resetting the log file between reads, we'll be printing the entire log over and over again. This should not be that difficult to be fixed though.
> - Since we're reading and printing the log in each iteration, we will have many many many prints in the pipeline each adding additional "steps". Combined with the previous point, we'll almost never then get a step with the entire log.

Regarding the two concerns:

1. **Preventing Repeated Log Printing**: Instead of reading and printing the entire log file in each iteration, you can track the last read position and only print the new content.
   That can be achieved by maintaining a variable that stores the last read line number and using a command like `tail` or `sed` to read from that line onwards.
2. **Managing Pipeline Steps**: To avoid excessive step creation in the pipeline, you can limit the frequency of log reading and echoing.
   Instead of doing it in every iteration of the loop, introduce a counter and perform this action only after a certain number of iterations.

The amended script would then be:

```
def runInBackground(stageName) {
    sh script: "nohup python ${stageName}.py > ${stageName}_output.log 2>&1 & echo \$! > ${stageName}_pid.txt", returnStdout: false
}

def readNewLogContent(stageName, lastLineRead) {
    def newLastLineRead = sh(script: "wc -l < ${stageName}_output.log", returnStdout: true).trim().toInteger()
    if (newLastLineRead > lastLineRead) {
        def newContent = sh(script: "tail -n +${lastLineRead + 1} ${stageName}_output.log", returnStdout: true).trim()
        echo newContent
    }
    return newLastLineRead
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Execute and Monitor') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def parallelStagesMap = [:]
                    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                        def stageName = "Stage-${i}"
                        parallelStagesMap[stageName] = {
                            node {
                                runInBackground(stageName)
                                def pid = readFile("${stageName}_pid.txt").trim()
                                def lastLineRead = 0
                                def iterationCounter = 0
                                while (sh(script: "ps -p ${pid}", returnStatus: true) == 0) {
                                    if (fileExists("${stageName}_summary.json")) {
                                        // Logic to update the report here
                                        // ...
                                    }
                                    if (iterationCounter++ % 5 == 0) { // Adjust the modulus value as needed
                                        lastLineRead = readNewLogContent(stageName, lastLineRead)
                                    }
                                    sleep(15)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                    def stageName = "Stage-${i}"
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: "${stageName}_output.log"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `readNewLogContent` function reads only new content from the log file since the last read position.
The `iterationCounter` variable is used to control the frequency of log reading. The modulus value can be adjusted based on how often you want to read the log. Adjust the modulus value in the `if (iterationCounter++ % 5 == 0)` condition to balance between the frequency of log updates and pipeline step creation.
The `lastLineRead` variable tracks the line number up to which the log file has been read, ensuring only new content is printed each time.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't really work properly:
* First I get `RejectedAccessException: No such static method found: staticMethod java.lang.Thread start org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2`
* The scripts as part of each stage is executed on a separate `node`. So the `Thread` needs to run on the same `node` it's monitoring.
* All groovy code (including this `Thread`) run on the `built-in` node so it won't find the files.

Maybe we can adapt this and 1 thread for each stage but that would cause tons of slowness on the controller since we'll be consuming all the threads.

Comment: Another problem I see in your code is that the `Thread` will only run after all the stages have finished because the `post { always {} }` runs after the `stages` is completed. Even if it would run in parallel to the `stages`, there will be 2 additional problems:
1) you're starting the Thread and not joining it which means that the `Pipeline` will finish while the the `Thread` might still be running.
2) you're waiting for the `summary.json`  of each `stage` to be ready before moving to the next `stage`. So if the first `stage` takes the longest, we won't update the report until the very end.

Comment: @user3396919 OK, I have rewritten the answer to propose an alternative approach. Regarding the `RejectedAccessException` from the first version of my answer, I suspect it is due to Jenkins' security model, which prevents the execution of certain Groovy methods for security reason

Comment: Thanks for the update, but you're missing the important point from the question "This same python script creates a summary.json file >>>>>which includes the tasks and their progress/status. I want to poll this file from Jenkins to update a report that I display on the build's page while the python script is running.<<<<<".

Comment: @user3396919 OK, I have revised the answer to address your last comment.

Comment: thanks for the update. I do have a solution for efficiently update the build page regularly during the build so that's not an issue. You're updated code looks close to my option 3 in the original question. The problem with it though is that running in the background (with the `&`) eould be killed directly afterwards unless you add the dont-kill-me cookie. Also, you'll need to get process ID in the same command since the second `sh` would run in a separate shell and won't know about the first command. Finally, the main problem is that we won't be getting the log from python script anymore.

Comment: @user3396919 OK. I have updated the script to address your last comment.

Comment: thanks again for the updates. Although this solution _should_ work, there are 2 problems with it:

* Since we're not resetting the log file between reads, we'll be printing the entire log over and over again. This should not be that difficult to be fixed though.
* Since we're reading and printing the log in each iteration, we will have many many many prints in the pipeline each adding additional "steps". Combined with the previous point, we'll almost never then get a step with the entire log.

Comment: @user3396919 OK, I have edited the answer to include a revised version of the pipeline, which should address your two problems from your last comment.